# How to deal with URLs with commas in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to use Graph API to get some information about URLs.

It works like this:

> http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=URL,URL2,URL3

However, when an URL contains comma, things get complicated. For

> http://www.example.com/name,something

we get

> http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fname%2Csomething

what gives us:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: something",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

What can be done with URLs to avoid such errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just double-URL-encode the comma, so use %252C for it:

http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fname%252Csomething

It might look weird, because then the Graph API identifies this URL by `http://www.example.com/name\u00252Csomething` - but I just tested it by pointing a like button to a URL containing a comma (un-encoded), liked it – and afterwards it showed 1 share for this URL on the Graph.

Comment: Note that this can be a bit tricky with the `requests` library, which will automatically percent-encode any values you pass to `params` (i.e. comma becomes just %2C)